# Communities where men didn't put their טליתות over their heads?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, rambam, tallit-gadol, head

I heard that the Rambam in his commentary to the Mishna mentioned cases where the custom of the place was different, one such place being יָוָן, where men didn't cover their heads with their tallitot, does anyone know where exactly this is mentioned or of any other sources talking of the same thing?

Comment: See the Shaari Tshuvah on hilchos tzitzis where it says to cover ones head with the talis during davening.

Answer (score 2):

I found this blog that had a post of an article about R' Akiva Eiger's shul where no one wore their talis on their head.
http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2012/11/on-minhag-not-to-wear-tallis-over-head.html

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that was really creepy account of what happened there. But thank you anyway.